# Rails Create Action Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My simple form is not doing a POST. I've been looking at this and haven't been able to see what is wrong (I'm sure it's in my routes). Here's what I have:

view:

```
views/buyers/new.html.erb

    <%= form_for(@buyer) do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :make %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :model %><br />
            <%= f.submit %>
          <% end %>
```

controller:

```
BuyersController
  def new
    @title = "Welcome to Car Finder"
    @buyer = Buyer.new
  end 

  def create
    @buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
    if @buyer.save!
      redirect_to success
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
   end
```

routes:

```
resources :buyers
```

rake routes:

```
                    buyers GET    /buyers(.:format)                buyers#index
                           POST   /buyers(.:format)                buyers#create
                 new_buyer GET    /buyers/new(.:format)            buyers#new
                edit_buyer GET    /buyers/:id/edit(.:format)       buyers#edit
                     buyer GET    /buyers/:id(.:format)            buyers#show
                           PUT    /buyers/:id(.:format)            buyers#update
                           DELETE /buyers/:id(.:format)            buyers#destroy
```

When I submit the form, it stays on the same page, never going to the create action. Below is from the log

```
Started GET "/?..[params]..."
Processing by BuyersController#new as HTML
```

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: What does your create action look like in the Buyers Controller? Please share.

Comment: what error you are getting on form submission?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. I don't get an error. It just adds the params to the URL and stays on the same page

Comment: I thought it could be the redirect_to :back in the else of the #create action, but I put a debugger above it and it never gets to that method

Comment: please post the generated html code in pastebin.com or pastie.org. I guess you missed some javascripts...

Comment: Here is the generated HTML, http://pastebin.com/R1mFhMeW -This is just a simple rails app and I'm using the included Javascripts.

Comment: its not a javascript problem. Do you actually have a success action (buyers/success.html.erb)? If you do it needs to be shown as a symbol (e.g. :success) in your `redirect_to`. That said you should really be doing something like `render :success`. All that said once the post action is complete where are you sending the user?

Comment: @rhoddee, you're right, I should update to a render :success. Currently though, that page does exist and is shown as a symbol. But I don't think that's the issue. I'm not even getting to the creat action.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably wise to restart your server. You're issue may lie in validations you have at your persistence level or in your `buyer.rb` file. Add this to the _form.html.erb:

```
<% if @buyer.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@buyer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this from being saved:   </h2>

  <ul>
  <% @buyer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Try to complete the request again. See if any errors are being thrown. Fix those.